# ampl looping, repeat until loop , syntax error

Tags: ampl

I just started on ampl and tried some easy algorithm basics .
Why is something like this repeat until loop not working ?

```
param x=8 ;
repeat until x=0;  
    param x=x-1;

display x;
```

test.mod, line 3 (offset 33):
syntax error
context:  repeat until x=0  >>> ; <<<

Comment: Although I don't know the programming language, most probably you need to use colon `:` (or maybe no symbol at all) instead of semicolon `;` at the end of the `repeat until x=0` statement

Comment: thank you for your comment , but I already tries something like that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the `repeat until` loop in AMPL is the following (see, e.g., page 262 of https://ampl.github.io/ampl-book.pdf):

```
param x;
let x := 8;
repeat until x == 0 {
    display x;
    let x := x-1;
}
display x;
```

It will produce the following output:

```
x = 8

x = 7

x = 6

x = 5

x = 4

x = 3

x = 2

x = 1

x = 0
```

Note that `param x = 8;` needs to be replaced by `param x; let x := 8;` since otherwise you would not be able to change its value.